# jQuery confirm window - cancel button not resetting value

Tags: jquery, forms

I've got some jQuery that displays a confirm box if the user chooses a value of 'Yes' in a select field.

In the confirm box, if the user clicks the OK button, I want the value to remain as it is. If the user clicks the Cancel button, I want the value to change back to what it was previously.

I've almost got this working with the code below, except that when the user clicks the Cancel button, the value remains as 'Yes' instead of returning to 'No'.

Any help in fixing this would be appreciated.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#publish_details').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == 'Yes')
    { window.confirm("Are you sure you want to publish these details?"); }
    });
});
</script>

<select name="publish_details" id="publish_details" />
    <option value="No" selected="selected">No</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,

Ste

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't setting a new value if not confirmed:

```
if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){ 
    if (!window.confirm("Are you sure you want to publish these details?")){
        $(this).val('No');
    }
}
```

Or you can simply return the confirm value (false if not confirmed):

```
if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){ 
    return window.confirm("Are you sure you want to publish these details?");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've gone with the first option as that worked perfectly. I wasn't quite sure what the second option was meant to do as clicking 'Cancel' didn't change the value back to No (unless I was just implementing it wrongly) but the first option did exactly what I needed so no worries. :-)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get it to work with the following code.

The HTML

```
<select name="publish_details" id="publish_details" />     
    <option id="no" value="No" selected="selected">No</option>     
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option> 
</select>
```

The javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#publish_details').change(function(){
        if($(this).val() == 'Yes'){
            var r=confirm("Are you sure you want to publish these details?")
            if (!r){
              $('#no').attr('selected', 'selected');
           }
         }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'd just implemented the other answer when your post came in, but thanks anyway as it's good to see the different ways of doing this.